# Assigning newly created and modified workbook into a variable for further use

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl, pywin32

I'm trying to write a simple program for automating my work with excel file and Outlook. What I'm trying to achieve is to collect excel file, modify it and after that save it into a variable so I can use this file as an attachment.

My code looks pretty much like this, I've omitted the functions for obtaining, modifying and the whole tkinter stuff as this works fine.

```
def prepareExcel():
    wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    wb_obj.save(filename = 'Test'+datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")+'.xlsx'

def Emailer():
    mail.Attachments.Add(filename)
    mail.Display(True)
```

I can't figure it out how to assign my newly created and saved workbook into a variable so I can use it as an attachment in my e-mail.

Comment: What isn’t working for you? You probably need an absolute path for the file, as Excel and Outlook will probably have different working directories.

Comment: But how should I add an absolute path to that attachment as this file will have different name each day? What isn’t working? When I click the button to create an e-mail I don’t have any attachment. I want this to happen automaticaly

Answer (score 0):

Why can't you just do something like the following;
Create the filename for the day and use that in both functions;

```
def prepareExcel(fn):
    wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    wb_obj.save(fn)

def Emailer(email_file):
    mail.Attachments.Add(email_fn)
    mail.Display(True)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    filename = 'Test'+datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")+'.xlsx'
    prepareExcel(filename)
    Emailer(filename)
```

Or return the filename from the prepareExcel function then use the returned name in the emailer.

```
def prepareExcel():
    filename = 'Test'+datetime.now().strftime("%Y%m%d")+'.xlsx'
    wb_obj = openpyxl.load_workbook(path)
    wb_obj.save(filename)
    return filename 

def Emailer(email_file):
    mail.Attachments.Add(email_file)
    mail.Display(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
     Emailer(prepareExcel())
```